# Adding the missing month's records for the for each product sales and show the product name for the newly added months instead of NULLs

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Adding the missing month's records for the for each product sales and show the product name for the newly added months instead of NULLs

I am using PL SQL. I cant use Insert or Update statements. However, I am using select * from Dual.

```
select * from 
    (select 'A' as ProductName,100 as Sales, 1 as MonthNumber from dual 
    union
    select 'A' as ProductName,200 as Sales, 3 as MonthNumber from dual
    union
    select 'A' as ProductName,150 as Sales, 5 as MonthNumber from dual
     ) A
     right join
    (select 1 as MonthNumber from dual 
    union
    select 2 as MonthNumber from dual 
    union 
    select 3 as MonthNumber from dual
    UNION
    select 4 as MonthNumber from dual
    UNION
    select 5 as MonthNumber from dual
     ) B
    on A.MonthNumber = B.MonthNumber
    full join
    (select 'A' as ProductName from dual) CD
    on  A.ProductName = CD.ProductName
    order by B.MonthNumber
```

Base Table: (Missing sales records for months 2 and 4)

```
PRODUCTNAME SALES   MONTHNUMBER
A           100      1
A           150      5
A           200      3
```

Date Table: (So I decided to right Join a temp date table which has months from 1,2,3,4,5)

Now My result set looks like below.

```
PRODUCTNAME SALES   MONTHNUMBER MONTHNUMBER
A           $100.00    1                1
(null)          (null)     (null)       2
A           $200.00    3                3
(null)          (null)     (null)       4
A           $150.00    5                5
```

This is partially correct. But the product Names are showing NULL for month number 2 and 4

Desired Output:

```
   PRODUCTNAME  SALES   MONTHNUMBER MONTHNUMBER PRODUCTNAME
    A           $100.00     1           1           A
    (null)      (null)      (null)      2           A
    A           $200.00     3           3           A
    (null)      (null)      (null)      4           A
    A           $150.00     5           5           A
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Awww..I just found the answer to my own question. I just need to use "Partition by". Here is the query for my desired output.

```
select * from 
(select 'A' as ProductName,100 as Sales, 1 as MonthNumber from dual 
union
select 'A' as ProductName,200 as Sales, 3 as MonthNumber from dual
union
select 'A' as ProductName,150 as Sales, 5 as MonthNumber from dual
 ) A
 PARTITION by (A.ProductName) right join
(select 1 as MonthNumber from dual 
union
select 2 as MonthNumber from dual 
union 
select 3 as MonthNumber from dual
UNION
select 4 as MonthNumber from dual
UNION
select 5 as MonthNumber from dual
 ) B
on A.MonthNumber = B.MonthNumber
ORDER by B.MonthNumber
```